# Segment fault while reading a string into a char* array

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read some strings and then print them into a matrix form.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",buffer[i]);  /**This line is causing segment fault **/
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < strnlen(buffer[i], MAX); j++ )
        {
            printf("%c ",buffer[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Any suggestion what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you sure your buffer is null terminated?

Comment: You've declared an array for BUFFER_SIZE strings, but haven't allocated any memory for the strings themselves. Is `buffer` only supposed to be one string?

Comment: Manvendra Singh, What is the value of the pointer `buffer[i]` when `scanf("%s",buffer[i]);` is called?

Comment: Tip: `scanf("%s",...);` is a bad as `gets(buffer[i]);`  do not use either.  Use `fgets()` to read a line of user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]` is an array of character pointers. The way your code is now, `buffer[i]` is a `char *` that is uninitialized at the time you `scanf("%s",buffer[i])`. You need to allocate memory (`malloc`, perhaps) for `scanf` to store the string of characters prior to this point.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to correct the code with calling malloc just before the scanf.